# Entity Framework 5.0 DBContext template with WCF attributes Support

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-5, poco

I am working on a Dot Net project with Entity Framewok 4.0 POCOs and WCF services in VS 2010.
because of performance improvements and table valued function support i am going to switch to Ef 5.0 and VS 2012.

but i searched a lot and did not 
find any poco generator template or DBcontext generator template that support DataContract and DataMember attributes to use in VS 2012 and EF5.x.

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Transactions))]
public partial class Accounts 
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string AccountCode { get; set; }
  }
```

and my questions are :

1- is there any one who has such a template that works in VS2012 ?

2- does anyone know the changes required in EF 5.x DBContext generator to Customize the template to Support WCF needed attributes.

I have very little time and i realy need help.

thanks for any help or Guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I use VS 2012 and I downloaded the extension "EF 5.x DbContext Generator with WCF support" in order to generate POCOs entities already decorated with WCF attributes.

By using this context generator you do not need to further customize the template.

[image]

Comment: I found the EF 6.x DbContaxt Generator with WCF Support but not the 5.x. What happens with the 5.x ?

Comment: You should check in "Tools>Extensions and updates". If I search using "EF 5.x db" I get it as available result.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply add the needed attributes in a partial class implementation in another code file.  Otherwise, you'll need to edit the .tt file.  I suggest the former one usually does this anyway to use data annotations (i.e. MetadataTypeAttribute).